# Traits and Rust

Tags: rust, traits

Was looking at some Rust code, and noticed the following block of code:

```
pub trait Foo: Bar {
    // methods omitted
}
```

I was wondering what exactly this code does. I'm familiar with this:

```
impl Foo for Struct {
    /// methods omitted
}
```

but have never come across the former before.

Comment: The link that describes what you are asking about is [this one](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#using-supertraits-to-require-one-traits-functionality-within-another-trait) and also [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/supertraits.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That block defines a new trait called `Foo`, which then allows you to use the trait in various places such as the `impl` block you have posted. The `: Bar` part says that any type that implements `Foo` must also implement the `Bar` trait.